# How to combine two lists while removing duplicates item from dynamic input in python

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

`[{'groups': ['Engineer', 'It', 'Office Floor 2', 'Penang']}, {'groups': ['Engineer', 'Penang', 'Testnew']}]`

All I wanted to do is separate it to delete duplicated item in the list, for example:

`['Engineer', 'It', 'Office Floor 2', 'Penang', 'Testnew']`

I tried with this code:

```
list_1 = ['Engineer', 'It', 'Office Floor 2', 'Penang']
list_2 = ['Engineer', 'Penang', 'Testnew']

set_1 = set(list_1)
set_2 = set(list_2)

list_2_items_not_in_list_1 = list(set_2 - set_1)
combined_list = list_1 + list_2_items_not_in_list_1

print(combined_list)
```

Although it worked but how can I modify it to a dynamic list? Since my list is not static and it may change according to how many user input.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to automatically remove duplicates from your list? Then just keep using a set?

Comment: All i want is remove the the json format such as `[{'groups': }]` then only store the list inside it. For example: `['Engineer', 'It', 'Office Floor 2', 'Penang']`. After that i need to combine this two list and remove only duplicate item in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the orders of appearance is a constraint, you could do:

```
lst = [{'groups': ['Engineer', 'It', 'Office Floor 2', 'Penang']}, {'groups': ['Engineer', 'Penang', 'Testnew']}]

seen = set()
result = []
for d in lst:
    for e in d["groups"]:
        if e not in seen:
            result.append(e)
            seen.add(e)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['Engineer', 'It', 'Office Floor 2', 'Penang', 'Testnew']
```

If the order of appearance is not a constraint:

```
from itertools import chain
result = list(set(chain.from_iterable(d["groups"] for d in lst)))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['Office Floor 2', 'Penang', 'Testnew', 'It', 'Engineer']
```

Or simply:

```
result = list(set(e for d in lst for e in d["groups"]))
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this -

```py
set_1 = list(set(list_1 + list2))
```

Or, if you want to keep adding items later, you can do it as such:

```py
set_1 = set(list_1 + list_2)
user_input = input("Add more stuff: ")
set_1.add(user_input)
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, but this is the static way. Since I'm not sure how many list will be input by the user , so i cant hard coded the list as `list1` and `list2`

Comment: That doesn't matter. Whatever the user inputs, just append it to the lists and then `list(set(list_1 + list_2))`

Comment: Otherwise, you can not convert the set to a list, use `set_1.add('new input')` and the input will be added if it's a new item, or ignored if it's already in the set

Comment: @terry5546 u can put all of them into a list and add them into one list in a for loop, or try something like this `set([*list_1 + *list_2 + *list_3 + ...])`

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this:

```
from itertools import chain
lst = [{'groups': ['Engineer', 'It', 'Office Floor 2', 'Penang']}, {'groups': ['Engineer', 'Penang', 'Testnew']}]
list(set(chain.from_iterable(map(lambda d: d['groups'], lst))))
```